# double dimensional array as return value

Tags: c

For my homework, I have to read data from an input file and to store it in a double dimensional array and then pass this array to another function. This is what I have tried so far, but I don't know when I call this function in main it gives the error:

> Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

I have tried to dynamically allocate memory and it gives the same error. What I am doing wrong?

The last update of the code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

int *a[2];
void getData(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int number;

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);


    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        a[i]=(int*)malloc(number * sizeof (int));
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &a[i][0], &a[i][1]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}


int main()
{   
    getData();
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n",a[i][0],a[i][1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `a`

Before the for loop

```
a = (int **)malloc(number * sizeof(int *))
```

Comment: @Kirilenko - Yeah it's useless in C. But since he has a similar cast in his original code, I thought may be he is compiling on C++.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating the first dimension, ie a is a null pointer when you are trying to dereference it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
a = malloc(number * sizeof *a);
```

BTW, `sizeof(int)` is not sufficient to store two numbers.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
a[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof *a[i]); 
fscanf(iFile, "%d %d", &a[i][0], &a[i][1]);
```

Here is a whole correct code (although not perfect, as long as `a` is an hugly global variable):

```
int (*a)[2] = NULL;

void getData(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int number;

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);
    a = malloc(number * sizeof *a);

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &a[i][0], &a[i][1]);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: it's still not working and it gives the same error. Maibe it's something else wrong in my function.

Comment: I've tested it, it's working as I expect. What's your check code?

Comment: a = malloc(number * sizeof *a) -> a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int(*)[2]" ->this is the first error

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling on C?

Comment: I discovered a new way to use the sizeof operator.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Explanations?

Comment: Anyway, you are funny, downvoting all my answers. :-)

Comment: Well there isn't a real error, just I think that using the explicit type as argument of sizeof would be more clear.

Comment: It is just your personal opinion. I don't agree, but it is mainly a style issue. No reason to downvote here.